# How to copy and paste bulk data from Excel to Html Table and then save to Laravel

Tags: laravel, html-table, import-from-excel

I want to copy and paste bulk of data, let's say 5-6 rows from the Excel sheet to the front end at once in the same format and then hit save and that data will be saved to the database using Laravel. I am not concerned about how do I save the data (I can do it) but I am concerned about how to bulk copy and paste multiple rows and columns to the front end.

How can I achieve this?

Let's consider this as Excel sheet table,

[Link Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro)

I want to copy all the rows and to paste them at my front end so that I can save the data. How can I achieve this kind of bulk copy-pasting? Any suggestions or reference or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just build a CSV importer? Probably an easier way to go about it.

Comment: you mean read the CSV file and extract the data?

Comment: You could use something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636969/3226121). Create textarea on the page and the button. When user clicks the button, you parse the string from textarea, and send it to backend

Comment: @azeem Amin your question sounded like you are wanting to import data from Excel to your database? If so you want to import data from a CSV, you could do a normal xlsx file but CSV is easier to import